# MySQL: how to properly structure a music database from Spotify API (albums and artists)

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, spotipy

I am playing around with [spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/) and MySQL, trying to set up a simple database containing artists, albums and songs say of a given genre.
I have now a simple question regarding the structure of such a database:

Since an album often have many artists indicated as authors, how do I encode properly in tables this information?

What I tried:
I created an `Albums` table with `album_id` as primary key, without indicating the artist (which for many albums the API returns a list of artists).

[image]

My initial idea was to then create an `Artists` table and reference there the `album_id` for each album of each artist, but this way I realized the `Artists` table would easily get messy and maybe would be better to have `artist_id` as primary key there, but then I cannot link an album to its artists.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a many to many case.

1. An album can have many artists
2. An artist can have many albums

ERD can model such relationships in theory. However for implementation, you'll need to create another table (linker table/junction table/join table) where it holds the album_id and artist_id.